# Intergrating ATK4 with wordpress development

Tags: php, wordpress, atk4

I found a article on the atk4 blog http://agiletoolkit.org/blog/integrating-agile-toolkit-with-wordpress/ I followed the instructions and i get a error and it says the ApiWeb Class not found. Then I looked in index.php on the real framework that you download and it initializes everything differently then the blog post did so. I'm wondering if ATK4 can be integrated or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also currently integrating a wordpress site with ATK4 at the moment.

The ApiWeb.php class is present in the atk4/lib directory in both 4.2 and 4.1.3 versions of atk4 so not sure why you are getting an error.

What is suggested on the blog page about integrating ATK4 with wordpress is that you would load the ATK4 libraries as php embedded in the pages so you would need to ensure you change the include line based on where you have placed the atk4 files.

```
 <?php
   include 'atk4/loader.php';
   $api=new ApiWeb('sample_project');
   $api->add('jUI');
    ..   ..   ..
   $api->execute();
 ?>
```

I havent tried this but think you would need to verify the path to ATK4 is correct.

I've taken a different approach to integrating Wordpress and ATK4 - rather than embedding ATK4 into the pages as per the blog article you referenced, i'm going with installing wordpress in one installation and ATK4 in a separate one and using the same template in both.

The wordpress template i'm using is from [themeforest](http://themeforest.net/category/wordpress?ref=twjnorth) and it came with a WP folder containing the Wordpress files plus a HTML folder that contains example pages.  I took one of the HTML pages and created a new templates/default/shared.html inserting the atk4 tags such as  in the appropriate places.

I've created a menu in Wordpress Theme->xxx->Menu which are mostly static pages from Wordpress and one menu option which is a link to the start of the ATK4 root.  Because i'm using the same template, it looks like a single site.  In my case, i'm not using the login functionality of Wordpress - all the wordpress pages will be accessible without logging in but i am using a dynamic second level menu and options based on the logged in user which will be defined in Frontend.php

The ATK4 menu gave me a problem because it wasnt consistent with the site and after a while trying to style the menus with CSS and create a submenu using Menu_Basic and Menu_Lite, i went with using ATK4 Views and split the HTML from the wordpress theme, to create a menu.html, a submenu.html and a menuitem.html and have set this using code in Frontend.php

It's still a work in progress so i can't provide the link at the moment as it's not online yet but it seems to be working and may give you other ideas depending on what you want to achieve with integrating ATK4 and Wordpress.

If you want to have a common login for ATK4 and Wordpress (using ATK4 to control the access each user has), there is a plugin for Wordpress that might help with [external DB Auth](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/external-database-authentication/) so you could use this with the BasicAuth of ATK4 instead of using Wordpress Auth functionality.

Comment: Wow cool glad there's somebody else working on atk4 for integrating it into WordPress. I'm taking a different approach to integrating it, I'm trying to make it work with building actual WordPress Plugins thought of it sense it works with jquery so nicely. But it just gives me errors in the wp-admin. I'm thinking sence WordPress plugins its not actually just one ".php" parsing its several Classes, Functions, Hooks all firing at ones that may be why its giving me the errors. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since I posted, i have created an ATK4 Model for wp_post and a view which matches the recent post html in my wordpress template.  I've then added a tag in the shared.html and empty.html and can get a list of recent posts displayed in my ATK4 pages, the same as those shown in the wordpress footer on pages and posts - will link here when i put the new site online so you can see yourself.  I had to modify a couple of things because both ATK4 and Wordpress use some common CSS class names and IDs such as for styling button and footer so i removed the ones from the wordpress template.